# PiVPN and Stunnel

Tags: raspberry-pi, openvpn, stunnel

I've been searching online for a tutorial on configuring stunnel with PiVPN but haven't found anything. Wondering if anyone has had any experience?

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to publicly announce you're attempting to hack through Chinese security while living in China.

Comment: Haha fair point